# JAXB 2.x with MOXy (Eclipselink 2.1.2): persisting XHTML as element value

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy

**IMPORTANT: updated with solution!**

See [JAXB 2.x with MOXy (Eclipselink 2.1.2): persisting XHTML as element value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712772/jaxb-2-x-with-moxy-eclipselink-2-1-2-persisting-xhtml-as-element-value/7715127#7715127)

---

I want to store XHTML as a node value of an XML via JAXB, e.g.

```
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
```

should get stored "as is" in an XML:

```
<root>
  <title>Title</title>
  <content>...the above XHTML snippet of paragraph...</content>
</root>
```

As I am using MOXy as JAXB Impl, I wanted to try this (**version 2.1.2**):

```
@XmlCDATA
public void setContent(String content) {
  this.content = content;
}
```

However, the content gets marshalled as escaped code and I can't display it afterwards as XHTML snippet.

First of all: Where can I download the latest release of MOXy? It might be a bug in 2.1.2. The maven repo is somehow not available anymore:
http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo

The link was found at 
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Maven

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update and solution regarding MOXy version 2.3.0:**
I have tried out version 2.3.0 of EclipseLink now and it works!

Here is my data object that I persist:

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlCDATA;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name=DialogMessage.ROOTNAME, namespace="...")
public class DialogMessage {

    @XmlTransient
    public static final String ROOTNAME = "dialog";

    @XmlElement(name="content-html", namespace="...")
    @XmlCDATA
    private String contentHTML = null;

    public String getContentHTML() {
        return contentHTML;
    }

    public void setContentHTML(String contentHTML) {
        this.contentHTML = contentHTML;
    }

}
```

and the MOXy enabling config files:
`package-info.java`:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "...", 
    xmlns = {@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "z", namespaceURI ="...")},  
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 
package com.yourdomain.packagenametodataclass;
```

and the `jaxb.properties`:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

When I write an instance of DialogMessage as XML to disk, the XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<z:dialog xmlns:z="...">
   <z:content-html><![CDATA[<p>sgd <strong>asdf</strong> asdf&#160;</p>
<p>asdf</p>]]></z:content-html>
</z:dialog>
```

Please note that "..." is just a replacement for whatever namespace URI you have.